# Inserting into mysql using express and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm wondering what would be the best route to populate a MySQL database with querys I pull from a script using express and node js.

The script I'm running on port 3000 looks like this:

```
curl localhost:3000/register?name=bob\&width=13.970000\&time=0
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=0.000000\&right=0.000000\&time=0 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=10 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=20 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/other?ir=0\&time=30 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=3.000000\&right=3.000000\&time=100 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=110 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=120 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/other?ir=0\&time=130 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=3.000000\&right=3.000000\&time=200 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=210 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=220 --cookie "USER=bob"
```

My app.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

let app = express()

app.use(cookieParser());

var pool = mysql.createPool( {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'cars',
        connectionLimit: 10,
        multipleStatements : true
});

app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
                mysql.pool.query("INSERT INTO todo (`name`) VALUES (?)", [name], function( err, results ) {
                        if (err)
                                throw err

                response.send(results);
                })
        });




app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
        console.log('Express JS ready for port 3000');
});
```

My database is set up in phpMyAdmin and looks like this:
[My database using phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCzE7.png)

When I run the script on port 3000, the error I keep getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

Eventually I want to populate the MySQL database using /wheels, /line, /echo, etc.. but the more I mess with it the more I get similar errors. Anyone see where I might be going wrong or can point me in the right as to where I might learn how to properly do something like this? Thanks

Comment: You don't need mysql.pool, just pool as it's declared as a variable

Comment: Thank you! Now the error I'm getting is: ReferenceError: name is not defined

Comment: Because name is a query parameter and not defined yet, you'd need req.query.name, Reference Error is usually solved by working out what's missing and/or incorrect. Debugging is useful and is a skill all programmers should have, once learnt, things like ReferenceErrors won't slow you down.

Comment: Debugging is very useful, it's a skill I'm familiar with when writing C++.. I just don't know node js or express that well. I've only finished a couple youtube tutorials and I'm still really lost. My campus is closed down so I have no where to get help besides on the internet for right now.

I messed around with the app more and now when I run the script I'm getting "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"
 When all I did was change the query arguement to : 
pool.query("INSERT INTO cars (`name`) VALUES (?)", [req.query.name], function( err, results )

I also changed mysql db to be not strict

Comment: if you're good at debugging C++, it should be easily applied to Node.js and Express, the language shouldn't matter. In regard to the empty response, double check that results is defined using console.log, I'd assume it isn't so it's giving an empty response.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I finally got it link and add to mysql database. Now my only issue is to figure out how to get all the app.get()'s to add to the same data set. Is there anyway to wrap all these app.get's into one command to populate the data set upon connection or something? As of right now it will write the name and width but 0's for everything else.

Comment: What do you mean by dataset? Table or database? "As of right now it will write the name and width but 0's for everything else" are you wanting to set defaults? Im a little lost, if you can update your original question with more code examples, I can probably get you in the right direction, I guess the simplest question for you to answer would be: what are you expecting to happen? If you can answer that, it would help toward an accurate answer

Comment: I know, I struggled quite a bit explaining it. Pretty much what I’m hoping for is to be able to populate my cars database until each column was filled and then move onto populating another row of columns after that. Keep on populating them until the script hits the \end. I’m told I should be using things like cookie-parser but I have had no luck. If this doesn’t make any sense still let me know and I will do my best tomorrow morning, with a fresh mind, to explain what I’m trying to do. I probably butchered it really bad in the question heh

Comment: I actually did some updates to this project and here is where I’m at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61813051/updating-a-mysql-data-table-from-query-parameters-using-nodejs-and-express/61813310?noredirect=1#comment109335254_61813310

Comment: Okay I'm following, so you're looking to automatically populate the database with new entries, separated from the routes? In a simpler form: you don't need to make a request for the population to happen? Assuming I'm correct, would an example of a similar mechanism help?

Comment: Yeah, I think that’s what I’m trying to do. I just run the script on port 3000 and then I want it to populate the database with each curl it gives out. Once one row of the data table is filled, I want it to create a new entry for the next round of curls. If you have any similar examples, I would LOVE to look them over. I’m dedicating my weekend to this project. I feel like, even with all the mistakes I’m making, that by doing a project like this I will learn more than what I got from simply following the YouTube tutorials on node js and express. Fun stuff!

Comment: ahhh so on request, good news is then you're almost there. Curl is a utility for making a HTTP request (in case you weren't aware), I'll write an example as an answer, hopefully it'll be understandable. Stateless would probably be the best approach (removing the need for sessions and cookies (bonus IMO)), with stateless there's no concept of next round, just this round (simplified). Youll learn more by doing then by learning, practice is more than theory (not that theory isn't important), even in failure you'll learn a lot. I'll put my answer up in a short while.

Comment: If my example doesn't demonstrate the problem let me know, I re-read your question after sleeping and I'm not sure if you're trying to group all into one get, for example, wheels, lines, register would also share the same app.get?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// file: server.js
const express = require('express');
const db = require('./db');
const app = express();

// you may wish to reconsider the use of .get at some stage
// what happens when you want to retrieve an item?
app.get('/models', (req, res) => {
  // learn about validation when you're comfortable with basics
  // this is especially important for public facing apps
  if (!req.query.manufacturer || !req.query.type || !req.query.cost) {
    return res.status(400).send('wrong input!'); // super helpful error messages
  }

  const public = req.query.public || true; // set defaults
  const { manufacturer, type, cost } = req.query;

  // when you're more comfortable, learn about abstractions + Service pattern
  // removing DB queries from route handlers, pushing the responsibility to a Service.
  db.query(
    'INSERT INTO car_models(manufacturer,type,cost,public) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
    // learn about SQL injection, I **hope** the mysql package author considered it.
    [manufacturer, type, cost, public],
    (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send('oh no');
      }

      return res.status(201).send(`Created ID: ${results.insertId}`);
    }
  );
});

app.listen(3000, () =>
  console.log('service started... accepting requests on http://localhost:3000')
);
```

```js
/**
 *  File: db.js
 *  Responsibility: connect to MySQL
 *  Note: you could use an ORM here (**could** not always **should**)
 */
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'develop',
  password: 'development',
  database: 'cars',
  port: 3306,
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`MySQL: Failed to connect to MySQL: ${err.message}`, err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('MySQL: Successfully connected to MySQL');

  connection.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car_models (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    manufacturer VARCHAR(30),
    type VARCHAR(10),
    cost BIGINT,
    public BOOLEAN
  );`);
});

module.exports = connection;
```

I had another example in mind, for the simplicity I've kept a style similar to yours, I hope this helps your understanding of it.

If there's anything you're unsure about, I recommend researching it. I don't recommend researching everything upfront. I tend to research things as/when I need them, or whenever I get the chance. (commuting for example)

You'll learn more through practice than researching, although it's important to find some form of balance. If not, you'll end up learning how to do something in a language and be restricted to only that language and only a small subset of the languages capabilities. (maybe, maybe not).

Adding a new car model is as simple as:
`curl http://localhost:3000/models?manufacturer=bmw&type=m3&cost=10000`

Or, try opening `http://localhost:3000/models?manufacturer=bmw&type=m3&cost=10000` in whatever browser you use (when it's running), and see what happens. You may find the browser (or Postman), will be easier to work with. Or you may not.

There's one very important part: no sessions, no cookies, no knowledge of the last request, nothing. This is stateless. For simple operations, there's no need to introduce such mechanisms as it's simply not required.

I'd suggest learning how Express.js can be structured (it's very flexible), there's patterns and best practices that you can follow, but maybe wait until you're comfortable with the language first, otherwise it can be a rabbit hole.

My final point, learn about the differences in stateless and stateful systems. Don't spend hours, take maybe 5 minutes so you understand the key concepts behind each. You can then use that knowledge to make your own decision about stateless vs stateful.

Something I wished I learned sooner: to solve a problem, you need to understand the problem you're trying to solve. Sounds basic, but I still get this wrong occasionally.

Good luck and all the best!

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried to re-engineer this to work with what I'm doing and I couldn't get anywhere with it really. It worked sort of like my first example did, but it wasn't creating new databases upon a table being filled out.. I'm going to post another update to the project here soon with what I've got. Right now, all I need to figure out is how to get node js/express to create a new data table once one is filled up.

Comment: Here's the updates I've made so far, hopefully they will give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842957/node-js-express-how-to-create-new-datatable-once-another-one-is-full