# Updating a mysql data table from query parameters using nodejs and express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Alright, I think I'm getting closer and closer to figuring this out. Right now I'm running a script like the one below on port 3000.

```
curl localhost:3000/register?name=bob\&width=13.970000\&time=0
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=0.000000\&right=0.000000\&time=0 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=10 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=20 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/other?ir=0\&time=30 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=3.000000\&right=3.000000\&time=100 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=110 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=120 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/other?ir=0\&time=130 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=3.000000\&right=3.000000\&time=200 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=210 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=220 --cookie "USER=bob"
```

I'm then using nodejs and express to add these query parameters to a database. Everything is working with '/register', as I'm able to store data in my database for 'user' and 'width', but when I try to update that same tables 'left1' and 'right1' properties from '/wheels' then the most I've been able to do is insert the data into a whole new table, one in which name and width are both back to default values.

In the end, what I'm trying to do is have the app create a new database entry in the cars database filling in the name, width, left1, right1, time, dist, l1, l2, l3, ir data rows and then create another entry in the database once all those are filled in... But all I can do right now is get it to enter a ton of different data sets that only have the name (bob) and width (14) properties filled out..  Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mysql = require('mysql');

let app = express();


var pool = mysql.createPool( {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'secret',
        database: 'cars',
        connectionLimit: 10,
        multipleStatements : true
});


app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    pool.query("INSERT INTO cars (`name`, `width`, `time`) VALUES (?,?,?)", [req.query.name, req.query.width, req.query.time]);
});

app.get('/wheels', function (req, res) {
        pool.query("UPDATE `cars` SET `left1`=?, `right1`=?",
        [req.query.left, req.query.right]) });


app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
        console.log('Express JS ready for port 3000');
});
```

And here's a picture of the database: [phpMyAdmin database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnq9A.png)

Any idea where I might be going wrong? I was told to perhaps try something with the sessions and cookies, but I've been looking up online about things like 'cookie-parser' and 'cookie-sessions' but I've been going no where with them. I have no clue how to use them to do anything with mysql database and I can't find anything online that is related to what I'm trying to do with it... SO confused. Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) there should not be quotes around the table/column names. Try using:

```
app.get('/wheels', function (req, res) {
        pool.query("UPDATE cars SET left1 = ?, right1 = ?",
        [req.query.left, req.query.right]) 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right that that's probably the right syntax. But it's still not updating the database with the wheel data. left1 and right1 are both 0's for each database entry. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Can you try to add `console.log(req.query)` in your /wheels handler please?

Comment: Hmm, I should of thought about doing that early! They show up as undefined. That's a problem.. When I add

console.log(req.query.left);
console.log(req.query.right);

to the /wheels, they show up as undefined.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this with your curl command for wheels and a simple express-app with the exact same /wheels handler (without the session/cookie stuff). Maybe you can disable session/cookie handling just to debug?

Comment: Hmm, I tried once again and I wasn't able to recreate it either. But, I think I made some progress. I added:
res.redirect('/wheels')

as the very last command for the app.get('/register', req, res) portion of the code, and it actually added the left1 and right1 data to the database like I needed it too. It might be an ugly option, but possibly I can just chain a bunch of res.redirect() commands and get it to enter that way?